# pandas create column with names from values and substitute with True/False

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3], "val":["A12", "B23", "C34", "A12", "C34", "E45", "F56", "G67", "B23"]})
print(df)
```

```
   id  val
0   1  A12
1   1  B23
2   1  C34
3   2  A12
4   2  C34
5   2  E45
6   2  F56
7   3  G67
8   3  B23
```

How do I convert it to look like this?

```
   id  A12  B23  C34  E45  F56  G67
0   1    1    1    1    0    0    0
1   2    1    0    1    1    1    0
2   3    0    1    0    0    0    1
```

I tried pivot and unstack but since the number of values in the 'val' column can be different for each 'id', I'm not able to create a master list of columns and then somehow fill the values in those columns. Please help.

Comment: Looks like, in the expected output, column C34 should have values [1 1 0] in place of [1 0 0]

Comment: You're right. Thanks Anshul. Edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try crosstab:

```
pd.crosstab(df.id, df.val).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks SimonR. I did not know about crosstab. The solution below using get_dummies and groupby works as well but it took more than twice the amount of time taken by the crosstab solution when I tested on a pandas dataframe of 100,000 rows. crosstab took around 13 seconds but get_dummies and groupby took 27 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Another way with `get_dummies` and `groupby`:

```
(pd.get_dummies(df.val)
   .groupby(df['id'])
   .sum()
   .reset_index()
)
```

Or `set_index` and `get_dummies`:

```
(pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('id').val)
   .sum(level='id')
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
   id  A12  B23  C34  E45  F56  G67
0   1    1    1    1    0    0    0
1   2    1    0    1    1    1    0
2   3    0    1    0    0    0    1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) and then [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
print( pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df['val'])], axis=1).groupby('id').sum().reset_index() )
```

Prints:

```
   id  A12  B23  C34  E45  F56  G67
0   1    1    1    1    0    0    0
1   2    1    0    1    1    1    0
2   3    0    1    0    0    0    1
```